# test for a property in ember object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Let's say:

```
Foo.user = Ember.Object.extend({
    username:null,
    name:null,
    loadData:function(data){
        _.each(data, function(value, key){
            console.log(this.hasOwnProperty(String(key)), key, String(key));
            console.log((String(key) in this));
            console.log(key in this.__proto__);
            console.log(_.has(this, key));
            ...
        });
    },
})
```

Where data is an Object ex. JSON

Is there any Ember way of testing or just a JS OO way??

Yes it is underscore... ;)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: just playing with ember. Anyway, testing for the props before creating the object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, context error, my apologies...poor me.

```
Foo.user = Ember.Object.extend({
  username:null,
  name:null,
  loadData:function(data){
      _.each(data, function(value, key){
          console.log(this.hasOwnProperty(String(key)), key, String(key));
          console.log((String(key) in this));
          console.log(key in this.__proto__);
          console.log(_.has(this, key));
          ...
      }, this);
   },
})
```

Comment: Maybe, does ember "extend" the prototype?

Comment: If this isn't a solution to your question, it shouldn't be posted as an answer. You can edit your original question to include any additional information you want. If this *is* the solution, then please disregard.